# TOSCA module coming empty when I call it through test case creation folder

Tags: tosca

[Module view from module folder which has all detailes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ten55.png)
 [Test case view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4vW1.png)

I just created a module in TOSCA  with two test steps. However, when I call it through the test case creation folder it is coming empty. Not showing module details. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following:
Click on the test case

Go to view tab in the ribbon

and make sure you toggle Hide DoNothing  or Show DoNothing.

OR

Delete the existing Demo Web Shop.search

After Creating the Scan of your module. (If already done ignore)

Just drag the module and drop it in TestCases Folder.

Any changes you make to the module will be automatically reflected in the TestCases folder.

Hope this should help..

Answer (score 0):

Select the the test case and Click on F9

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on checkout tree in home tab.
When the module is not checked out and used for teststep by drag and drop, at that time it shows only name of module and not the controls.

Answer (score 0):

4 years late, but the answer is with the "Hide DoNothing" button, as mentioned in other answers.

The button will hide every ModuleAttribute that is empty within a TestStep. The button is bound to F9 and is meant to filter out empty ModuleAttributes for easier viewing.

Additionally, in the TreeView, a Test Step will only show ModuleAttributes that have been changed so that they have an Action. They will still appear in the Details pane, assuming "Hide DoNothing" is disabled.